# ZXing.Net.Mobile for Forms - Issue when tried to build app

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, zxing

I am using **Xamarin.Forms**. Recently I added bar-code scanner using **Zxing**
https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile.forms.
when I am trying to Debug app it is working fine but when I am trying to build app, I get the following error?

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error     The "LinkAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.XamarinAndroidException: error XA2006:
>   Reference to metadata item 'System.Void
>   Xamarin.Forms.Element::set_AutomationId(System.String)' (defined in
>   'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms, Version=2.1.47.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null') from 'ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms, Version=2.1.47.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' could not be resolved. --->
>   Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void
>   Xamarin.Forms.Element::set_AutomationId(System.String)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
>   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()    at
>   Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)    at
>   MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, LinkContext&
>   context)    at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()    ---
>   End of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Java.Interop.Tools.Diagnostics.Diagnostic.Error(Int32 code, Exception
>   innerException, String message, Object[] args)    at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute()    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() SellDirect9000.Droid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the configuration for release to be same as debug:

> Android Options -->Linker --> Linker properties -->linking(changing
>   form "Sdk Assemblies Only" to "None")

but it don't know if this solution is good because the size for apk increased

Comment: I can't find Android Options in Xamarin. Any help with that please?